# Group dynamic IP blocks for multiple firewall rules

Tags: centos, firewall

I am on a dynamic IP which is defined by my ISP's set of IP blocks. I want to open ssh, ftp, MySql and so on, to that set of blocks. I don't want to have to specify all the entries for each rule. Is there a way to setup all the allowable addresses as a group that is then assigned once to each port I want access to?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a set of `IPs` using `ipset` then you can add any restriction on it.

For example to create an `ipset`:

```
ipset -N myset hash:ip,port
```

To add `ip` with `port` to the set:

```
ipset add myset x.x.x.0/24,80-82 
ipset add myset x.x.x.x,udp:53 
ipset add myset y.y.y.y,vrrp:0
```

Then to create rule on this set you can use `iptables` for firewall:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set myset dst -j ACCEPT
```

The `ipset` commands above create a new set (myset of type iphash) with two addresses (`x.x.x.x` and `y.y.y.y`).

The `iptables` command then references the set with the match specification `-m set --set myset dst`, which means "match packets whose destination  header matches (that is, is contained within) the set named myset".

The flag `dst` means match on "destination". The flag `src` would match on "source", and the flag src,dst would match on both source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

You mention CentOS but not a specific version.

## CentOS 6

In CentOS 6, your firewall could look something like this in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:INTERNAL - [0:0]
:INTERNAL_allow - [0:0]
:LOGGING - [0:0]

#LOGGING Chain
-A LOGGING -p tcp -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables DROP: " --log-level 4

#INPUT Chain
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INTERNAL
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

#INTERNAL Chain to define networks (only networks that match continue to INTERNAL_allow)
-A INTERNAL -s 192.168.10.0/24 -g INTERNAL_allow
-A INTERNAL -s 10.9.8.0/24 -g INTERNAL_allow

#INTERNAL_allow Chain to define allowed ports on those networks
-A INTERNAL_allow -p icmp -j ACCEPT
#open a single port using tcp module
-A INTERNAL_allow -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#open multiple ports using multiport module
-A INTERNAL_allow -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dport 21,3306 -j ACCEPT
```

See also:

- `man iptables` for `multiport` and `tcp` modules as well as `-g` parameter.

## CentOS 7

You could probably use zones in firewalld.  I'm not too experienced with it.